# jQuery multiple select option search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 selection boxes and I want to get all option selected values into a variable like this: val+val+val+val
Below you can see my code, but it's not full working because if I have nothing selected I get +++++

```
if($('select').attr("selectedIndex") == 0) {
        var allVariables = $("select option:selected").map(function(){ 
            return this.value 
        }).get().join("+");
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It was returning empty values because your select option headers still represent a user selection, they just have no value. So add in a check for a value before you return it:

```
$('.find').click(function(e){
var Scat = $('#Scat option:selected').val();
var allVariables = $("select option:selected").map(function(){ 
    if(this.value!=""){ //only return if we have a value
    return this.value;
    }
}).get().join('+');

alert(allVariables);
if(Scat == ""){
    alert("Choose a Category");
} else {

    // do something else
};
});
```

Comment: *I want to get all option selected values* - I reckon they need to be selected

Comment: @oGeez "but it's not full working because if I have nothing selected I get +++++"

Comment: In fact I think you are correct, the question is awkwardly worded - apologies.

Comment: @AdrianAxinte what do you want to happen when they're not selected?

Comment: @Ed Pitt - if is not selected just remove the value from the variable

Comment: @AdrianAxinte But surely there is only ever going to be one `<option>` selected? Why would you need to concatenate?

Comment: @AdrianAxinte does your code actually work if you do have them selected? I've realised your question mentions checkboxes but your code appears to refer to selects with options

Comment: like I said I have 5 select boxes - (search filter), first is for the main category if($('#Scat option:selected')){ do something else alert - and the other 4 are not required. I need a variable with those 4 like: seed+size+profile

Comment: It's not full working, because now if I have only 1 option selected I get ++size+ and I need only size. So if there's 2 options I need size+profile etc

Comment: `allvariables` need to exclude `Scat`, also `if(Scat = 0){alert}` it's not working!? :(

Comment: @AdrianAxinte Scat will never be 0. the only values you have are '', '2222', '3333'

Comment: @AdrianAxinte you need if(Scat == "")

Comment: @Ed yes, but I want to check if it's not empty (is :checkded)

Comment: @AdrianAxinte 'checked' doesn't apply to selection boxes. You just need to check for an empty value string (Scat == ""). I've edited my answer for this new requirement of yours