# jQuery filter search with multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 select boxes and I want to get last 4 options selected values into a variable like this: `val+val+val+val`
First select box is for choosing the category so that it's working.

Below you can see my code, but it's not full working because if I have nothing selected I get `++++`

```
<select name="Scat" id="Scat">
    <option value="">Select Manufacturer</option>
    <option value="2222">Michelin</option>
    <option value="3333">Continental</option>
</select>
<select name="Ssize" id="Ssize">
    <option value="">Select Size</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
</select>
<select name="Sprofile" id="Sprofile">
    <option value="">Select Profile</option>
    <option value="60">60</option>
    <option value="80">80</option>
</select>
<a class="find" href="#">find</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.find').click(function(e){
    var Scat = $('#Scat option:selected').val();
    var allVariables = $("select option:selected").map(function(){ 
        return this.value 
    }).get().join("+");
    alert(allVariables);
    if(Scat = 0){
        alert("Choose a Category");
    } else {
        window.location = "http://something.com/category="+Scat+"/search="+allVariables;
        //http://something.com/category=2222/search=60+30/
    };
});
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kj6Rr/

Comment: Didn't you [ask this earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20120138/1612146)?

Comment: yes, sorry I just want to fix that :(

Comment: Are we not talking about this over here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120138/jquery-multiple-select-option-search-results/20120202?noredirect=1#comment29986196_20120202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point: You used `=` as an comparison operator, but in JavaScript you have to use `===` or `==`.

The main problem is caused by the `join('+')` method. If there are only those 2 relevant dropdowns I would suggest to enter them each of them manually:

```
$('.find').click(function(e){
    var size, profile, Scat, searchString;
    Scat = $('#Scat option:selected').val();

    if(!Scat){
        alert("Choose a Category");
        return;
    }

    size = $('#Ssize option:selected').val();    
    profile = $('#Sprofile option:selected').val();
    if size && profile) {
        searchString = size + '+' + profile;
    } else if (!size && !profile) {
        searchString = ""; 
    } else if (!size) {
        searchString = size;
    } else if (!profile) {
        searchString = profile;
    }

    window.location = "http://something.com/category="+Scat+"/search=" + searchString;
});
```

Fiddel http://jsfiddle.net/Kj6Rr/5/

Comment: thanks, but `size` and `profile` is not required, so how can I remove the variable from `window.location` if the option is not selected?

Comment: Check edited post. But if you have problems creating this script on your own, I would suggest you read some tutorials. This is really easy scripting.